# How to render a table with dynamic columns and values in jsrender?

Tags: jsrender, jsreport

I have a dataset like

```
{
"columns": [
  {
    "name": "COLUMN1",
    "code": "c1"
  },
  {
    "name": "COLUMN2",
    "code": "c2"
  },
  {
    "name": "COLUMN3",
    "code": "c3"
  },
  {
    "name": "COLUMN4",
    "code": "c4"
  }
],
"rows": [
  {
    "c1": 387,
    "c2": 347.618,
    "c3": 0,
    "c4": 39.282,
  },
  {
    "c1": 390,
    "c2": 3457.618,
    "c3": 0,
    "c4": 40.282
  },
        {
    "c1": 387,
    "c2": 3447.618,
    "c3": 0,
    "c4": 39.282
  },
        {
    "c2":10,
    "c3": 0,
    "c4": 39.282
  },
        {
    "c1": 387,
    "c2": 347.618,
    "c4": 100
  }
]
}
```

In which the length of the columns as well as the length of the rows is not fix. Now i want to render a table with table headers as `column.name`
an the row values should be accessible via the column code. (like for column COLUMN1 the value for each row should be row.c1 and so on).

I have combined a lot of answers on SO and some documentation on jsrender and come up with a solution which is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{for columns}}
                <th class="right">{{:name}}</th>
            {{/for}}

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        {{for rows}}
            <tr>
                {{for columns ~data=#data}}
                    {{props #data}}
                        {{if key == "code"}}
                            <td class="right">{{:~data[prop]}}</td>
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/props}}
                {{/for}}
            </tr>
        {{/for}}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Can any one give me a better approach to do this? The only mapping between the columns array and the rows array is the code field. 
Please comment if you need any further information.

P.S: I can't change the data structure at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can do:

```
{{for rows}}
    <tr>
        {{for ~root.columns ~row=#data}}
            <td class="right">{{:~row[code]}}</td>
        {{/for}}
    </tr>
{{/for}}
```

Comment: I tried `{{:~row[{{:code}}]}}` but it dint struck me to use this simple form `{{:~row[code]}}`. Awesome, thanks for the help.

Comment: it gives parsing error

{{for ~root.columns ~row=#data}}

Comment: The syntax is correct. What does the error message say? Are you using a recent version of jsrender/jsviews? If so, and you have a parsing error, create a jsfiddle and I will check it for you.